# Passing double array from WPF to JavaScript function to create polygon using GoogleAPI

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, wpf

I am facing problem in drawing polygon using googleapi. Which needs to pass double array for latitude and longitude. JavaScript function is giving error.

For testing pupose I have two Arrays of type double. and values are assigned in code.

```
var lats = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), 4);
var longs = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), 4);
lats.SetValue(25.774252, 0);
lats.SetValue(18.466465, 1);
lats.SetValue(32.321384, 2);
lats.SetValue(25.774252, 3);

longs.SetValue(-80.190262, 0);
longs.SetValue(-66.118292, 1);
longs.SetValue(-64.75737, 2);
longs.SetValue(-80.190262, 3);
currBrowser.InvokeScript("drawPloygon", lats, longs);
```

Then I call a JavaScript function name 'drawPolygon' and pass two separate arrays. Which is working properly if I hardcode the triangleCoords in JavaScript Function 'drawPolygon'.

```
       function drawPloygon(lats,longs) {

        try {
         var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.483617, -1.889992),
            zoom: 8
             };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions)

            var length = lats.length;
            alert(lats);
            alert(longs);

             //Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.

            var triangleCoords = [];
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                triangleCoords[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(this.javaSerial.Serialize(lats[i]), this.javaSerial.Serialize(longs[i]));
            }

        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }

        var bermudaTriangle;
        // Construct the polygon.
        bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: triangleCoords,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });

        bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
    }
```

** Below are Hardcoded triangleCoords array wokring perfectly to draw polygon**

```
        var triangleCoords = [

          new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
          new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
          new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
          new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
        ];
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Remove `this.javaSerial.Serialize` calls
- Define `length` as the shorter of the two params:

  ```
  var length = 0;

  if(lats.length && longs.length)
    {
    length = lats.length > longs.length ? lats.length : longs.length;
    }
  ```